# Power BI Data Flow API calls using Timeout=#duration return no results

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-api

Trying to set the timeout property for my api calls to be longer than 30 seconds in Power BI data flow.

```
 Source = Json.Document(Web.Contents("https://[apiservice].com",[RelativePath=thepath],[Timeout=#duration(0,0,30,0)])),
```

The above results in no records ever returning. Removing the Timeout statement does allow records to be returned, but seems to drop records due to timeouts which I am trying to solve in the above.

Answer (score 0):

the default timeout is 100 seconds, maybe try and increase it to more than that.

Answer (score 0):

The #duration function creates a duration value, where the syntax is #duration(days, hours, minutes, seconds), so your code might bee something like this: #duration(0,0,0,30) would specify a 30-second timeout for the web request.